# Error "Did you compile with -rdynamic?" seen only when application installed using RPM

Tags: gtk, gtk3, glib, vala

I have a Vala application that loads modules just `gmodule-2.0`, when installed through usual `make install` means everything works correctly. When I build an RPM file and install (on Fedora 27) using `dnf install my-app` I get a whole bunch of errors like

```
(my-app:15094): Gtk-WARNING **: Could not find signal handler 'btn_thing_changed_cb'.  Did you compile with -rdynamic?

(my-app:15094): Gtk-WARNING **: Could not find signal handler 'adj_thing_value_changed_cb'.  Did you compile with -rdynamic?
```

Even after I add `-rdynamic` to the build and reinstall I continue to see these errors. Somewhere I read that I need to use `gmodule-export-2.0`, but the diff on it's `pkgconfig` and the one for `gmodule-2.0` shows that they're exactly the same. Soooo...

The application is written in Vala and built using `valac`. Also, the UI classes that I have are Gtk template classes which may be an issue, but the fact that it works when I install from source makes me think that it isn't.

Comment: This message appears, when you have callbacks defined in `.glade`, but no real handlers for those callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the default RPM build will strip the symbols out of executables. You can disable stripping by changing your `spec` file to include:

```
%global __os_install_post %{nil}
```

or:

```
 %global __strip /bin/true
```

Comment: That would appear to be the issue, when I dump symbols with `objdump` I get none that match my callbacks. Unfortunately neither of those remove the warnings when added to the spec. I am building my `.so` using `meson` and the `library` call, I'm wondering if `shared_library` wouldn't be more correct.

Comment: This could be a Meson configuration problem instead. Try adding `export_dynamic: true` keyword argument to `executable ()`. See the discussion at [Meson issue #2662](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/pull/2662)